# Wordpress and Elementor -the_content()

Tags: php, wordpress, elementor

I wish create new wordpress theme. For now i have front page and i have one question. 
I'm curious can i create multiple wordpress content area (places) for elementor on that page.

For now i can use only one content area with this code

```
<?php if (have_posts()) {
    while (have_posts()) {
        the_post();
        the_content();
    }
} ?>
```

Sample: Header and "Hero" section is static, below i wanna elementor section , bellow that i wanna something again static and after that i wanna again elementor section.

Code above give me only place for elementor.
Sry for stupid question and thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use only one content area.

Elementor is a *page builder* that aims to provide (or support via third party) all the functionality that you might need by using its widgets.
You can generate your own template for many types of posts/pages including the main WordPress types, e.g. blog, archive, single, etc...

Elementor-Pro extends the collection and there are many more plugins.

I think that reading their documentation and watching their videos will clarify more [Official Elementor Website](https://elementor.com)

Per the example above, Elementor has the widgets to display all posts in certain category etc... All you need to provide is `the_content()` call

Comment: Ok, only one content area per page. I will create widget places. Thanks